# How to convert List<object> to List<string>?

Tags: c#

I have a method that return a object List.

```
 public async Task<List<object>> FindAndSelectAsync(Expression<Func<LicenseModel, bool>> expression, Expression<Func<LicenseModel, object>> selectExpression, int startIndex = 0, int pageSize = 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var db = new ArmanRahsakhtDataContext();
            var result = pageSize != 0 ? await db.License.Where(expression).OrderBy(m => m.Id).Select(selectExpression).Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync() : await db.License.Where(expression).Select(selectExpression).ToListAsync();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

i use this method and get list of object, i want to convert this list to a List

```
 var data = (await licenseService.FindAndSelectAsync(m => m.UserId == userId,
                m => m.Name)).Cast<String>().ToList();
```

But get error `Special case is not valid`

Comment: Do you mean "special cast is not valid"?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than casting, why not change your method signature to make the method generic? Then we can accept `Func<T, TItem>` instead of `Func<T, object>`:

```
public async Task<List<TItemType>> FindAndSelectAsync<TItemType>(Expression<Func<LicenseModel, bool>> expression, Expression<Func<LicenseModel, TItemType>> selectExpression, int startIndex = 0, int pageSize = 0)
```

And then call it like so?:

```
var data = (await licenseService.FindAndSelectAsync<string>(m => m.UserId == userId,
            m => m.Name)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there no way to convert?  I do not want to change the method